# Как сделать, чтобы новый файл открывался в новой вкладке в Sublime text 3?

Tags: ide, sublime-text

1. Когда в **левом сайд баре** **кликаешь по файлу чтобы открыть**, **закрывается текущий файл** в рабочем пространстве и открывается этот файл, можно сделать так чтобы файл просто открывался в новой вкладке?
2. Когда **копируешь фрагмент кода** и **нечаяно нажал ТАБ** в месте куда хотел вставить франмент, скопораваний **текст просто исчезает!** как поправить?

Comment: 1. Это из-за того, что в текущем файле не было изменений.  На жмите пробел и работайте дальше, спокойно. На счет #2 не понял

Comment: Не задавайте два вопроса в одном.

Comment: 1. Открывайте файлы двойным кликом